# r shiny observe function clears text input

Tags: r, api, shiny

Hi I am trying to build a login page that contacts an API service and validates user credentials. If the credentials are correct then a new user interface appears and simply makes a plot. If it is not correct a message at the login screen should say "incorrect login". Currently, when I try to type in either of the fields at the login page (ui1.r) the field refreshes/wipes itself after a second or so, thus preventing me from passing on user input to the API. I have the following files

server.r:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)
umls <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), 
                  dbname="/media/sf_umls-2018AA-full/2018AA-full/2018AA/META/umls_browser.sqlite3")
licenseCode <- "mylicense"



shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  source('ui1.R') #login page



  output$page <- renderUI({ ui1 })

  observe({
    z<-system(paste("perl", "/media/sf_umls-2018AA-full/2018AA-full/2018AA/META/umls_auth.pl",
                    input$user, input$password),intern=TRUE)
    if (grepl("false",z[22])) {
      renderText("incorrect login")
    }
    if (grepl("true",z[22])) 
    {
      output$page <- renderUI({ ui2 })
      output$table <- renderTable({mtcars()})
    }
  })

})
```

ui1.r

```
ui1 <- shinyUI(fluidPage(


      # Application title
      titlePanel("UMLS Constraint Browser"),

      # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          textInput("user", "User",""),
          textInput("password", "Password",""),
          actionButton("login", "Login")

        ),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput("table")
        )
      )
    ))
```

What appears to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the `observe` function. Each time you write a letter, it sends a request to your credential database. You should try to use 
`ObserveEvent` instead :

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

observeEvent(input$login, {
z<-system(paste("perl", "/media/sf_umls-2018AA-full/2018AA-full/2018AA/META/umls_auth.pl",
                input$user, input$password),intern=TRUE)
if (grepl("false",z[22])) {
  renderText("incorrect login")
}
if (grepl("true",z[22])) 
{
  output$page <- renderUI({ ui2 })
  output$table <- renderTable({mtcars()})
}  })

})
```

Here, a request is made only when the user clicks on the login button. Tell me if it works for you.